# Make elasticsearch only return certain fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch to index my documents.

Is it possible to instruct it to only return particular fields instead of the entire json document it has stored?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#_source, note thay you can also exclude only some fields

Answer (score 815, accepted):

Yep, Use a better option [source filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-source-filtering.html).  If you're searching with JSON it'll look something like this:

```
{
    "_source": ["user", "message", ...],
    "query": ...,
    "size": ...
}
```

In ES 2.4 and earlier, you could also use the [fields option to the search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-fields.html):

```
{
    "fields": ["user", "message", ...],
    "query": ...,
    "size": ...
}
```

This is deprecated in ES 5+.  And source filters are more powerful anyway!

Comment: make sure to define them as "stored": true in mapping. Otherwise ES will still load the _source document and load fields from there. May impact performance if returned data is relatively small to the size of a whole document.

Comment: you meant "store": true

Comment: are these made in the conf file or where exactly?

Comment: @vbNewbie: Where ever you are defining mapping.
If you aren't defining mapping explicitly and relying on ES to generate it, then you'll have to define mapping for fields you want ES to store. You can define mapping just for fields where you want special behavior (e.g. "store":true, "index":"not_analyzed") or all fields. Look into mapping docs for more details.

Comment: Moreover, fields are indexed by default but not stored separately, only whole document is stored as "_source". How to put your mapping in ES, I think would depend on your application / how you are indexing documents.

Comment: Is it possible to use "fields": ["user"] and make the result appear under "_source" property. Now I get the result under hits: [ { fields: { user: "someone" } } ]

Comment: fields is no longer supported on newer versions.
use stored_fields instead  :)

Comment: ```{
    "fields": ["user", "message", ...],
    "query": ...,
    "size": ...
}worked for me

Comment: The `fields` option seems to not be deprecated in Elasticsearch 8.3 in 2022. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html

Comment: How do you use_source for specific document fields and also return aggregations?

Answer (score 104):

I found the docs for the `get api` to be helpful - especially the two sections, **Source filtering** and **Fields**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/docs-get.html#get-source-filtering

They state about source filtering:

> If you only need one or two fields from the complete _source, you can
>   use the _source_include & _source_exclude parameters to include or
>   filter out that parts you need. This can be especially helpful with
>   large documents where partial retrieval can save on network overhead

Which fitted my use case perfectly. I ended up simply filtering the source like so (using the shorthand):

```
{
    "_source": ["field_x", ..., "field_y"],
    "query": {      
        ...
    }
}
```

FYI, they state in the docs about the **fields** parameter:

> The get operation allows specifying a set of stored fields that will
>   be returned by passing the fields parameter.

It seems to cater for fields that have been specifically stored, where it places each field in an array. If the specified fields haven't been stored it will fetch each one from the _source, which could result in 'slower' retrievals. I also had trouble trying to get it to return fields of type object.

So in summary, you have two options, either though source filtering or [stored] fields.

Comment: Did the trick for me. I had a problem with returning geo_point using "fields", but "_source" works just fine, thanks !

Comment: How do you use_source for specific document fields and also return aggregations?

Answer (score 32):

For the ES versions 5.X and above you can a ES query something like this:

```
    GET /.../...
    {
      "_source": {
        "includes": [ "FIELD1", "FIELD2", "FIELD3" ... " ]
      },
      .
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

Answer (score 26):

here you can specify whichever field you want in your output and also which you don't:

```
  POST index_name/_search
    {
        "_source": {
            "includes": [ "field_name", "field_name" ],
            "excludes": [ "field_name" ]
        },
        "query" : {
            "match" : { "field_name" : "value" }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

In Elasticsearch 5.x the above mentioned approach is deprecated.
You can use the _source approach, but but in certain situations it can make sense to store a field. For instance, if you have a document with a title, a date, and a very large content field, you may want to retrieve just the title and the date without having to extract those fields from a large _source field:

In this case, you'd use:

```
{  
   "size": $INT_NUM_OF_DOCS_TO_RETURN,
   "stored_fields":[  
      "doc.headline",
      "doc.text",
      "doc.timestamp_utc"
   ],
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":{  
            "term":{  
               "doc.topic":"news_on_things"
            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "range":{  
               "doc.timestamp_utc":{  
                  "gte":1451606400000,
                  "lt":1483228800000,
                  "format":"epoch_millis"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  

   }
}
```

See the documentation on how to index stored fields.
Always happy for an Upvote!

Answer (score 12):

Here is another solution, now using a **match** expression

[Source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) allows to control how the _source field is returned with every hit.

Tested with Elastiscsearch version 5.5

The keyword `includes` defines the specifics fields.

```
GET /my_indice/my_indice_type/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "my_especific_field"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "_id": "%my_id_here_without_percent%"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

[response_filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering)

> All REST APIs accept a **filter_path** parameter that can be used to
> reduce the response returned by elasticsearch. This parameter takes a
> comma separated list of filters expressed with the dot notation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35647027/844700

Answer (score 6):

A REST API GET request could be made with '_source' parameter.

Example Request

```
http://localhost:9200/opt_pr/_search?q=SYMBOL:ITC AND OPTION_TYPE=CE AND TRADE_DATE=2017-02-10 AND EXPIRY_DATE=2017-02-23&_source=STRIKE_PRICE
```

Response

```
{
"took": 59,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 104,
    "max_score": 7.3908954,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uLc",
            "_score": 7.3908954,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 160
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uLh",
            "_score": 7.3908954,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 185
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uLi",
            "_score": 7.3908954,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 190
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uLm",
            "_score": 7.3908954,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 210
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uLp",
            "_score": 7.3908954,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 225
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uLr",
            "_score": 7.3908954,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 235
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uLw",
            "_score": 7.3908954,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 260
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uL5",
            "_score": 7.3908954,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 305
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uLd",
            "_score": 7.381078,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 165
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "opt_pr",
            "_type": "opt_pr_r",
            "_id": "AV3K4QTgNHl15Mv30uLy",
            "_score": 7.381078,
            "_source": {
                "STRIKE_PRICE": 270
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: This is very use full for me.

Comment: The result shown above indicates a total hit of 104. Yet only 11 are shown up. How come?

Comment: I used this approach a lot, and always struggle to find any doc for it, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes by using source filter you can accomplish this, here is the doc [source-filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)

Example Request

```
POST index_name/_search
 {
   "_source":["field1","filed2".....] 
 }
```

Output will be

```
{
  "took": 57,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index_name",
        "_type": "index1",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "field1": "a",
          "field2": "b"
        },
        {
          "field1": "c",
          "field2": "d"
        },....
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are several methods that can be useful to achieve field-specific results.
One can be through the **source** method.
And another method that can also be useful to receive cleaner and more summarized answers according to our interests is **filter_path**:

Document Json in index "index1":

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "index1",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1,
    "_source" : {
      "year" : 2020,
      "created_at" : "2020-01-29",
      "url" : "www.github.com/mbarr0987",
      "name":"github"
    }
  }
```

Query:

```
GET index1/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source.url
{
  "query": { 
        {"term": {"name":"github" }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "url" : "www.github.com/mbarr0987"
            }
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In java you can use setFetchSource like this :

```
client.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type)
            .setFetchSource(new String[] { "field1", "field2" }, null)
```

Answer (score 3):

For example, you have a doc with three fields:

```
PUT movie/_doc/1
{
  "name":"The Lion King",
  "language":"English",
  "score":"9.3"
}
```

If you want to return `name` and `score` you can use the following command:

```
GET movie/_doc/1?_source_includes=name,score
```

If you want to get some fields which match a pattern:

```
GET movie/_doc/1?_source_includes=*re
```

Maybe exclude some fields:

```
GET movie/_doc/1?_source_excludes=score
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know sql, please write a query to get the code's value,for example sql query equivalent and elasticsearch query

```
POST /_sql/translate
{
  
  "query": "select name,surname from users"
}
```

result is ,be carefull look at the includes key

```
{
  "size" : 1000,
  "_source" : {
    "includes" : [
      "name",
      "surname"
    ],
    "excludes" : [ ]
  },
  "sort" : [
    {
      "_doc" : {
        "order" : "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> GET /_cat/indices?format=json&h=<comma_separated_field_names>

Answer (score 0):

In case, if anyone is looking for answer in Python using [`elasticsearch-dsl`](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```py
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import Match

included_fields = [list_of_fields]

match_all_query = MatchAll()

queryset = Search(using=es_conn, index=index_name).query(match_all_query).source(included_fields)

response = queryset.execute()
```

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is unhelpful: you don’t say which Python module you used, and the official `elasticsearch` one doesn’t define such classes.

Comment: @bfontaine sorry about that, i fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks; I added the library as well because this is not only an answer "for Python", but "for Python with `elasticsearch_dsl`". I for example use Python without that library.