# Is there a way to exclude a field in an Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I know to use the fields setting to include just the fields I want in a search http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/fields/

... but I was wondering if I could do the opposite ... somehow specify one or two fields that I don't want included in the query results (like an attachment, for example). It just seems painful to have to type out all the fields I want minus one or two, when I could just specify fields to exclude

Comment: Just to be clear, the "fields" parameter you linked to doesn't affect the fields the query is run against, just what is returned... (I think you know this, more for other people reading.)

Comment: Yes I knew that, thanks for clarifying though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make elasticsearch only return certain fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605292/make-elasticsearch-only-return-certain-fields)

Answer (score 43):

You can use Source Filtering (Tested in v. 1.6 and v. 1.7): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html

```
{
    "_source": {
        "include": [ "obj1.*", "obj2.*" ],
        "exclude": [ "*.description" ]
    },
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

You can also use it in GET request:

```
curl "localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/66a8f299870b4cab?_source_exclude=file._content&pretty"
```

The previous example exclude the file content in an attachment field.

Comment: Could you explain, please, the wildcard selector in this line: `"exclude": [ "*.description" ]`? Is `*.description` the same as (rewritten in regex): `.*\.description`? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @crollywood, the example is taken from ES official doc, It excludes all "description" subfields, so I think that your regexp would be correct.

Comment: `include` and `exclude` are deprecated now in the `_source` object, they are replaced by `includes` and `excludes` respectively.

Comment: My understanding is that _source only affects which fields are returned in the results, not which field are actually searched.

Answer (score 8):

Did you see the documentation for ‛partial‛ on the same page you linked in your question? That allows you to do what you want, albeit only on ‛_source‛ fields I believe. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-fields.html

> When loading data from `_source`, `partial` fields can be used to use
>   wildcards to control what part of the `_source` will be loaded based on
>   `include` and `exclude` patterns.
>
> Both `include` and `exclude` support multiple patterns:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "partial_fields" : {
        "partial1" : {
            "include" : ["obj1.obj2.*", "obj1.obj4.*"],
            "exclude" : "obj1.obj3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you could quote that documentation at the very least. Even if the OP missed something obvious, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, tried it but it didn't work, so I'm probably doing something wrong, just don't know what :\

Comment: @PaulBellora - fair enough. I was on a mobile device at the time of posting, so apologies to concept47.

Comment: @concept47, did you consider doing an `exclude` as you have in your Google Groups posting, but also do an `include` for `*`? Not sure if that's possible, but maybe? (It's a reach, I'll admit)

Comment: Well the problem was that all the fields were being returned anyway, so I didn't think that would impact it, but I'll try it out too

Comment: I am very confused, I just tried out the posted answer, both with and without the `"include"` section, and it worked for me. Can you post a Gist if you still need help.

Comment: I had to use the "query" close to enclose all of it, otherwise "exclude" doesn't do anything.