# exclude a field from resulted documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: json, lucene, elasticsearch

I want to exclude a field from resulted Documents in ElasticSearch. I went through this document of ElasticSearch.org http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html but this doesn't work when I try. I have seen the same question on SO [Is there a way to exclude a field in an Elasticsearch query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220883/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-a-field-in-an-elasticsearch-query) but unfortunately that also doesn't give the answer just pasted example from ElasticSearch site. Here is my code

```
{
        "query":
        {
             "multi_match": {
                  "fields": [
                  "user",
                  "email"
                  ],
                  "query": "John",
                  "operator": "and",
                  "type": "phrase_prefix"
              }
        }
    },
        "partial_fields" : {
        "partial1" : {
            "exclude" : "email"
        }
    },
        "from" : 0,
        "size" : 10
}
```

Here is the result of above query

```
{
"took": 5,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "abc",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "user": "John Smith",
                "email": "johnsmith_88@yahoo.com",
                "pic": "95052dc5bb0bd2575.01687359.jpg"
                "utype": "m"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "abc",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "user": "Johnathan",
                "email": "johnathan@ymail.com",
                "pic": "428952deea899c6ad3.87100416.jpg"
                "utype": "m"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

in the above query everything works fine but that gives result with **Email** field as well and I want to exclude this **Email** field from being in resulted documents.

Comment: Can you provide result of the query? I have a guess but first have to see response.

Comment: @shyos I have updated my code with result.

Comment: does above query is exact same query with yours? If it is, delete 1 curly bracket '}' after `type:phrase_prefix`.

Comment: Oh @shyos Thanks. How stupid I am. Thanks Alot that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is solved with that query has a typo. There are several ways to check your query before sending.

- Either install `elasticsearch-head` plugin, which helps you to query through simple and useful interface
- or, on basic level, you can use json parser websites. Such as: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Thanks for extra info and providing support. @shyos, I have posted another question please check if you can answer that as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285524/get-only-result-documents-in-elasticsearch-excluding-other-meta-data-with-php-li