# get only result documents in ElasticSearch excluding other meta data with PHP Library

Tags: json, elasticsearch

My current result of a query is as

```
{
"took": 13,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "ABC",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
                "partial1": {
                    "uid": "1",
                    "pic": "21398129082209.jpg",
                    "utype": "m",
                    "user": "John Smith"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

There are more than 100000 hits returnd on different 1000 queries per second.

I want to exclude other Meta Data information from my result specially **_index** and **type** as I am using PHP Library to retrieve documents and send it to client. So, this expose my **Index** and **type** to clients which can be security issue. Currently I am looping through result like

```
 $ttl = count($results['hits']['hits']);
 $lst = array();
 for($i=0; $i<$ttl; $i++)
 {
  $lst[] = $results['hits']['hits'][$i]["fields"]["partial1"];
 }
```

This is performance issue if there are thousands of requests simuntaneously. And sending resulted documents to client as they type something needs to be faster as much as possible. Is there some way out? There is a question on SO but that is about a year old and says it is currenly not supported. Or I just have to do what I am doing?

Comment: There is no way of doing this directly in ES. You need to do what you're doing already.

Comment: Are you 100% sure for this? :(

Comment: WOW @DrTech **Clinton** I just visited your profile and saw you work for ElasticSearch.com. That's great I got 100% answer.

Comment: @DrTech Hi, it's been over a year and there are tons of questions/request to be able to filter out metadata without sacrificing performance. Is this still 100% not possible? Tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the "filter_path" query parameter. It's very flexible. For example, to only include the _source field for all results (and thereby exclude all the other metadata in the response) use: `?filter_path=hits.hits._source`. Its been in the rest api since 1.6 I think.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/common-options.html#_response_filtering