# Elasticsearch match all except specified fields query, exclude

Tags: elasticsearch

My indexed Elasticsearch documents include many fields. I've been using [match_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) query to get results. There are a few fields I'd like to exclude from match_all, is this possible?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220883/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-a-field-in-an-elasticsearch-query, but the other one is from 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Elasticsearch you can use [partial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html#partial) fields to filter fields.

Example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "partial_fields": {
        "partial1": {
            "exclude": ["excludeField1", "excludeField2"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do the same in ES6. The above code does not works for me. it gives **[query_string] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [partial_fields]**

Answer (score 1):

For this question I will give you the example

```
GET index_name/index_type/_search
{
  "_source": {

  "exclude": [
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ElasticSearch 2.x, you can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-source-filtering.html), example:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "include": [ "obj1.*", "obj2.*" ],
        "exclude": [ "*.description" ]
    },
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

For a GET request you may also pass it [via the url](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-get.html#get-source-filtering).