# Exclude a field on a Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the following mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/testidx?pretty=true' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "items": {
       "dynamic": "strict",
       "properties" : {
            "title" : { "type": "string" },
            "body" : { "type": "string" }
}}}}'
```

I put two items on it:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/testidx/items/1' -d '{
  "title": "Titulo anterior",
  "body": "blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla"
}'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/testidx/items/2' -d '{
  "title": "Joselr",
  "body": "Titulo stuff more stuff" 
}'
```

Now I want to search the word `titulo` on every field but `body`, so what I do is (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320770/742269) post):

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/testidx/items/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
         "query_string": {
              "query": "Titulo"
         }},
         "_source" : {
              "exclude" : ["*.body"]
         }
    }'
```

It's supposed to show only the `1` item, as the second one has the word `Titulo` but it's on the `body` and that's what I want to ignore. How can archive this?

PS: This is just a simple example, I've a mapping with a lot of properties and I want to ignore some of them in some searches. 
PS2: I'm using ES 2.3.2

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html&rqid=iKqKTO4D&geid=lo

Comment: That's what I tried. Read my question first, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `_source/exclude` setting is only useful for not returning the `body` field in the response, but that doesn't exclude that field from being searched.

What you can do is to specify all the fields you want to search instead (whitelist approach)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/testidx/items/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query" : {
     "query_string": {
          "fields": ["title", "field2", "field3"],      <-- add this
          "query": "Titulo"
     }},
     "_source" : {
          "exclude" : ["*.body"]
     }
}'
```

Another thing you can do is to explicitly specify that `body` should not be matched with `-body:Titulo`

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/testidx/items/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query" : {
     "query_string": {
          "query": "Titulo AND -body:Titulo"                <-- modify this
     }},
     "_source" : {
          "exclude" : ["*.body"]
     }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks, Val. I'm looking for something like the second answer. The first one needs to list the other fields and that's what I want to avoid. The second answer seems valid with a `query_string`, but how can I make the query if I'm using `term` or `terms`? If I'm not wrong, that `-body` to exclude a field is only available in `query_string`, right?

Comment: Does the second approach mean that the word "Titulo" should not be present in body or it does'nt cares whether it is present in the body or not?

Comment: @RichaSinha yes that's correct, the results won't include documents with a body containing Titulo

Comment: Is there any way to just ignore, that means it should not care for whether it is present in body or not. So let us say i am running a query on all fields and i exclude body it should fetch me results where query string is present in the other fields and it should care about whether the query string is present in body or not.

Comment: @RichaSinha I'm not sure about your precise requirement, but feel free to create a new question with the exact details ans some sample documents/queries.

Comment: @Val I have created a new question. U might wanna have a look into it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757277/how-to-exclude-a-field-from-getting-searched-by-elasticsearch-6-1

Answer (score 0):

Up to `elasticsearch 6.0.0` you can set `"include_in_all": false` to your index field properties, see e.g. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/include-in-all.html.

(This of course needs a reindexing of the data.)