# Filter the fields returned by Elastic Search hits to enchance performance.(source filtering)

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, elastica

Indexed documents with around 70 fields.Some of them with store=yes but not indexed and others with store=no but indexed (with some analyzed and some not analyzed).Upon querying  our .net client (the one talking to ES cluster for search) is extracting complete documents(those matches the search).
We want to enhance performance and  but we dont need all the fields of the documents indexed(fields required vary from query to query passed as view columns).

On query level(jason query body) best way to do this filtering(source filtering may be not sure,googled but documentation is very immature).way to specify in the query that for this searchrequest body i want these fields?

Comment: i am using "field":["field1",field2"] on the top of query.Is this a textbook way to achive this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make elasticsearch only return certain fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605292/make-elasticsearch-only-return-certain-fields)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve source filtering for fields with store:false ,without loading the complete source document.?