# elasticsearch results without _ internal fields

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

How can I have elasticsearch query return results without _ internal fields such as _index, _type?

Reason: For several pages I use AJAX call to get results rather than render the entire webpage on server. But exposing  _index & _type internal fields for every document is not only redundant (bandwidth), its also exposing the index and type names (security issue).

Please help!

Comment: You should be querying for the fileds you are interested in. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605292/make-elasticsearch-only-return-certain-fields

Answer (score 0):

This question was discussed a while ago in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elasticsearch/Option$20to$20disabled$20_index$20$2C$20_type$20$2C$20_id$20info$20in$20the$20response/elasticsearch/lpqp1tCnD40/XI0x5tPRQScJ) of the elasticsearch google group.

In summary you can't hide those "internal" fields out of the box. I guess that you are not querying Elasticsearch directly (I hope your server is not open to the world) but an intermediate REST service, so, you can filter those fields there.