# How to query all documents, filter for a specific field and return the value for each document in Elasticsearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm currently running an Elasticsearch instance which is synchronizing from a MongoDB via river. The MongoDB contains entries like this:

```
{field1: "value1", field2: "value2", cars: ["BMW", "Ford", "Porsche"]}
```

Not every entry in Mongo does have a *cars* field.

Now I want to create an ElasticSearch query which is searching over every document and return just the cars field from every single document indexed in Elasticsearch.

Is it even possible? Elasticsearch must touch every single document to return the *cars* field. Maybe querying with Mongo is just easier and as fast as Elasticsearch. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query POSTed to `hostname:9200/_search` should get you started:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "cars"
    }
  },
  "fields": ["cars"]
}
```

The `filter` clause limits the results to documents with a `cars` field.

The `fields` clause says to only return the `cars` field. If you wanted the entire document returned, you would leave this section out.

References:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering

[Make elasticsearch only return certain fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605292/make-elasticsearch-only-return-certain-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch (from my understanding) is not intended to be a SSoT database.  It is very good at text searching, and analytics aggregations, but it isn't necessarily intended to be your primary database.

However, your use case isn't necessarily non performant in elasticsearch, it sounds like you just want to filter for your cars field, which you can do as documented here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html

Lastly, I would actually venture that elasticsearch is faster than mongo in this case (assuming that the cars field is NOT indexed and elasticsearch is, which is their respective defaults), since you probably want to filter out the case in which the cars field is not set.

tl;dr elasticsearch isn't intended for your particularly use-case, but it probably is faster than mongo assuming you filter out the cars field being 'missing'