# Elasticsearch URI search with wildcards

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I’m searching on ES using the URI search syntax. My query looks something like this: `http://local host:9200/library/book/_search?q=bookID:1234`

I want to match any `ID` starting from let’s say 12, I can use a regex for this such as 12*. But how do I use this in URI search? It does not seem to work and returns no matches even though they exist. The documents say I need to set `analyze_wildcards=true`, which I did. But the problem persists.

Comment: Are you using the ES query syntax?

Comment: You sure `http://local host:9200/library/book/_search?q=bookID:12*` doesnt work? what does your mapping look like?

Comment: You can use curl as well. [Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928109/elasticsearch-search-with-wildcards)

Comment: I figured it out. Regex matching does not work on number fields, only on strings. I changed my mapping to hold them IDs as strings.