# Adding source field to Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query which is hitting the below table. How can I add source field to it to return specific columns from the _source field of this index?

GET mktg_percolate_postmetrics_mib/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "end_date": {
              "gte": "now-30d",
              "lte": "now",
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "post_id",
        "size": 25,
        "order": {
          "1": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "doc['facebook_likes'].value + doc['facebook_shares'].value + doc['facebook_comments'].value + doc['facebook_post_consumptions_by_type_link_clicks'].value",
            "lang": "expression"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to look into [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)

Comment: Thanks @Val I was looking into it before. Adding source field doesn't result in anything for me. My query fetch highest engaging post in last 30 days based on the formula in the script tag.

Comment: Can you show how you have used the `_source` field in your query? Also can you tell in which client you are running your queries?

Comment: Which ES version are you using??

Comment: "_source": {
        "includes": [ "facebook_comments" ],
        "excludes": [ ]
  } Cant' everything. I added this before query as per the documentation

Comment: @Richa - Unable to find but my Kibana version is 4.5.4. It's hosted on a client's machine.

Comment: You can have a look at this answer. It http://stackoverflow.com/a/9605566/4188368

Comment: Thanks Richa. I tried with both _source and fields. I don't see any difference in the three outputs. Without  source or field, with _source, and with fields

Comment: You mean you get all the fields in `hits`. That's kind of strange.

Comment: No. I am not getting any. I will post the response here

Comment: {
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 16979,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "2": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": -1,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 16943,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 2804
          },
          "key": "23817530",
          "doc_count": 17
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 2098
          },
          "key": "22923723",
          "doc_count": 19
  }]}}}

Comment: I can not see any fields in `hits`What I can see over here is `aggregation bucket` response.  `Hits` array is empty.