# Elasticsearch source filtering object array

Tags: elasticsearch

For a doc indexed at Elasticsearch like:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": [1,2,3],
      "c": "abcd1"
    },
    {
      "b": [4,5,6,7],
      "c": "abcd2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can we apply source filtering such that the query returns only `b` nodes from all object(s) in `a`?

I've tried something like this:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [
      "a[*].c"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

But, it didn't work.

Comment: check this out.. You can select only the b field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605292/make-elasticsearch-only-return-certain-fields

Answer (score 1):

Since `"a"` is an array of objects to accomplish what you want, you need to define `"a"` as a `Nested` datatype. Please read "Array of Objects" note here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html

So you have to define "a" property as `nested` type in the mapping. I'm following the next steps from your example:

1.- Define the mapping

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "a": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

2.- Create document `1` with your sample data:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/_doc/1?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "a" : [
    {
      "b" : [1,2,3],
      "c" : "abcd1"
    },
    {
      "b" : [4,5,6,7],
      "c" :  "abcd2"
    }
  ]
}
'
```

3.- And here is how you query should be, please notice `nested.path` when you have to specify the path to where you really want to start the query, and then the normal query

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "_source": "a.b",
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "a",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

And this is the result with only `b` field in each object:

```
"took" : 4,
"timed_out" : false,
"_shards" : {
  "total" : 5,
  "successful" : 5,
  "skipped" : 0,
  "failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
  "total" : 1,
  "max_score" : 1.0,
  "hits" : [
    {
      "_index" : "my_index",
      "_type" : "_doc",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "a" : [
          {
            "b" : [1, 2, 3]
          },
          {
            "b" : [4, 5, 6, 7]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the ElasticSearch reference for Nested date types https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: If `a[...]` is response from aggregation query (i.e. avg aggs inside terms aggs) and I want only b (exclude c) then how to do source filtering?