# elasticsearch - only return specific fields without _source?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I've found some answer like
[Make elasticsearch only return certain fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605292/make-elasticsearch-only-return-certain-fields)

But they all need `_source` field.

In my system, disk and network are both scarce resources.

I can't store `_source` field and I don't need `_index`, `_score` field.

ElasticSearch Version: 5.5

Index Mapping just likes

```
{
  "index_2020-04-08": {
    "mappings": {
      "type1": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "_source": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
          "rank_score": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "first_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "second_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My query:

```
GET index_2020-04-08/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "first_id": "hello"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 1000,
  "sort": [
    {
      "rank_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The search results I got :

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index_2020-04-08",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "id_1",
        "_score": null,
        "sort": [
          0.06621722
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "index_2020-04-08",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "id_2",
        "_score": null,
        "sort": [
          0.07864579
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The results I want:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_id": "id_1"
      },
      {
        "_id": "id_2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can I implement it?

Comment: Please provide ES version. Just to be sure, you're not storing _source in ES documents? Can you share your mapping? Are you using stored fields?

Comment: @Alexandre Juma Thank you for your attention. I've provide more information and please take a look.

Comment: Can you also post your API Call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return specific fields in the document, you must do one of the two:

1. Include the `_source` field in your documents, which is enabled by default.
2. Store specific fields with the [stored fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-stored-fields) feature which must be enabled manually

Because you want pretty much the document Ids and some metadata, you can use the [filter_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) feature.

Here's an example that's close to what you want (just change the field list):

```
$ curl -X GET "localhost:9200/metricbeat-7.6.1-2020.04.02-000002/_search?filter_path=took,timed_out,_shards,hits.total,hits.max_score,hits.hits._id&pretty"
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_id" : "8SEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "8iEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "8yEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "9CEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "9SEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "9iEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "9yEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "-CEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "-SEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "-iEGSHEBzNscjCyQ18cg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It returned: `invalid version format: Q=ELASTICSEARCH&FILTER_PATH=TOOK,HITS.HITS._ID HTTP/1.1`

Comment: This seems like the right answer. But it doesn't work in mine.

Comment: I don't have a 5.5 setup but can you please post the full api call that threw that error?

Comment: It works well now and there was a typo. THANK YOU VERY MUCH@Alexandre Juma

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify based on the SO question you linked -- you're not *storing* the `_source`, you're *requesting* it from ES. It's usually used to limit what you want to have retrieved, i.e.

```json
...
"_source": ["only", "fields", "I", "need"]
...
```

---

`_score`, `_index` etc are meta fields that are going to be retrieved no matter what. You can "hack" it a bit by seeting the size to 0 and aggregating, i.e.

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which will save you a few bytes

```json
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "terms" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Ac76WXEBnteqn982smh_",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "As77WXEBnteqn982EGgq",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but performing aggregations has a cost of its own.